# C# Round Robin tournament scheduling with more than 2 players for round

Tags: c#, arrays, arraylist, methods, combinations

I want to make a free program for a BGG tournament but I am stuck on the algorithm of the match. I know what a basic round robin is and I have decided to do a round robin this year but it gets a bit complicated, at least for me, with a variable number of players and since it is a variable people for each match and since we have to set a max set of Round....so it isn't as simple as throwing the names in a tournament generator.

Normally a Round Robin Tournament is 1 vs 1 and the "1" could be a team of a fixable number of players (for example soccer a team is composed of 11 player) but what I want to achieve is something that has as input these variables:

```
List<Player> players
int playerCountForMatch
int numberOfMatchContemporary
int maxSetOfRound
```

and as output it gives to me a List in which each player play at least 1 time with all of other players.

Let's do an example:

```
INPUT

\\Let's say that the Player class has only one property called ID as int. and in this example we have 12 object inside the list
List<Player> players 

\\Let's say that is 4 player for each match
int playerCountForMatch

\\Let's say that there is physical 3 places to make the match
int numberOfMatchContemporary

\\Let's say that we want to make at least 2 Round
int maxSetOfRound
```

So the output could be:

```
Round 1: {01 02 03 04}   {05 06 07 08}   {09 10 11 12}
Round 2: {10 01 09 05}   {02 06 11 12}   {03 07 04 12}
```

Once I start trying to lay out combinations it just throws me off. I'm not sure if they're is a solid method to this or not. I doubt many round robins are ever done like this so I couldn't find much when searching.

I just want it to be as fair as possible. Any help is appreciated.